# fill cell in mat-table with ngfor and number

Tags: angular

I have a problem to fill a cell. I have a mat-table

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="score">
  <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
     {{'label.score'|translate }}
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <div *ngIf="element.score != null">
        <span *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(element.score);
           let i = index;">
           <mat-icon>star</mat-icon>
        </span>
     </div> 
   </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

ngFor doesn't create the stars with the variable element.score. If I replace element.score for the number 3 I have 3 stars in the cell but if element.score is 3, I have one star in the cell.

Thanks

Comment: You want to declare an array in typescript, and then reference it rather than using `[].constructor(element.score);`

Comment: I have tried, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

If element.score is an array you can just iterate over the elements:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of element.score; index as i;">
    <mat-icon>star</mat-icon>
</span>
```

---

Edit:

If you have only a number you can create your array in the component

```
  public createArray(length: number): number[]
    return Array(length).fill(0); // [0,0,0]
  }
```

and use this array in your template:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of createArray(element.score)">
    <mat-icon>star</mat-icon>
</span>
```

See also: [Angular Api for NgFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Comment: element.score is not an array, it's a number